# Can 4 = 6 and 10 = 1000? : Another Grandpa Question

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

Grandpa likes PSE. He is amazed at the smart puzzle solvers who seem to solve any of his riddles. So he constantly tries to think of new challenging questions.

So he says:

"Ask Tom, SteveV, Jafe, Rand, elguest, hex, Bass and other smart guys

Is it possible  to prove

> 4 = 6
>
> and
>
> 10 = 1000

using same logic (that is what I call it)

and no math operations?"

> uvag guvax ebgguvegrra

Comment: i assume rot13(gung gur nafjre vfa'g fvzcyl "ab")?

Comment: Correct SteveV. There is a funny logic to get to the answer

Comment: And you already have it!

Comment: Interesting thing. My university math teacher once said that our math is what we desided to accept long ago. We accepted that `2*2 = 4`, but we could have accepted that `2*2 = a fluffy white rabbit`.

Comment: Also i suppose rot13(lbh unir gb znxr n "abg rdhnyf" fvat vafgrnq "rdhnyf" fvta. Gung fgvpgyl fcrnxvat jba'g or n zngu bcrengvba, ohg n qenjvat bar.) is not the correct answer =)

Comment: No that is not the correct answer. Too obvious right? Grandpa wants you to prove that 4=6 and 10=1000 by some logic

Comment: "Using the same logic" along with lateral-thinking, which describes itself as "[...] may not be obtainable only using logic.". I really suck at PSE

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My final answer:
*For 4=6:*

> In Roman, 4 is IV.
> But rot13(IV) is VI!
> VI in Roman is 6,
> so 4=6.

Similarly
*For 1000=10*

> In Roman, 10 is X.
> But rot13(X) is *K*.
> K isn’t *roman* for 1000, but it does mean 1000.
> So 10=1000.

**Attempt 2(wrong again!)**:

My guess would be:

From @Rand al’Thor

> I think it might be something to do with
>
>  the fact that all of the puzzlers mentioned in the question - Tom, SteveV, Jafe, Rand, elguest, hex, Bass - have tag badges (bronze, silver, or gold) in the riddle tag.
>  Which makes it ironic that
>
>  I just edited the riddle tag out of your question because it's not a riddle! :-P
>  Which then makes me think that the numbers might have something to do with
>
>  the requirements for earning a tag badge. Specifically, the number of answers/votes you need for a silver one is 4 times the number you need for a bronze one, while the number you need for a gold one is 10 times that, which comes to 1000 votes. I just don't see the relevance of 6 ...

But I seem to have the answer.

For 10=1000

> The number of votes you need for a gold badge is *1000*, which is *10* times those for bronze.

For 4=6

> I just browsed the *six* user profiles, and except for [Rand al’Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor)
> and [El-Guest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50778/el-guest), the remaining *four* have silver or below in the [riddle](/questions/tagged/riddle) tag.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER(INCORRECT):**

Partial answer:

> 4=6
>  This can be proven by using Roman numerals
> 4=IV
> 6=VI
> IV=VI
> So 4=6

Then for part 2:

> 10 = 1000 if we consider 0 to have no value - literally!

Comment: IV = VI   ?  I do not get it. There is a different way Krad Cigol

Comment: Oh, ok. Is 10=1000 right?

Comment: No. Remember SAME LOGIC for both.

Comment: I suspect the logic is that in archaic roman numeral interpretation, they didn't have shortcuts like "IV" instead of "IIII".  They didn't pay attention to the order of symbols, just which symbols were present.  Assuming that description of archaic roman numeal interpretation is correct, which I'm not sure of.

Comment: quick note; `Tom, SteveV, Jafe, Rand, elguest, hex, Bass` I count 7...

Comment: @Jeffrey: you’re right, thanks! It turns out my original logic was partly right!

Comment: Hello. You finally have it (Rot13) But 4 = IV and Rot13 IV is VI =6. Please edit your answer  @Krad Cigol

Comment: Whoops, fixed! You had me fooled there, saying ‘VI=IV’ made no sense. Now I understand you wanted a better explanation. Thanks again!

Comment: Great solve and question @DEEM. $\pi = 105$ :)

Comment: PI = CV = 105  That is right! Great find @TOM

Answer (score 10):

I think it might be something to do with

> the fact that all of the puzzlers mentioned in the question - [Tom](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19547/tom), [SteveV](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51984/stevev), [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe), [Rand](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor), [elguest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50778/el-guest), [hex](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18422/hexomino), [Bass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/36023/bass) - have tag badges (bronze, silver, or gold) in the [riddle](/questions/tagged/riddle) tag.

Which makes it ironic that

> I just edited the [riddle](/questions/tagged/riddle) tag out of your question because it's not a riddle! :-P

Which then makes me think that the numbers might have something to do with

> the [requirements for earning a tag badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags). Specifically, the number of answers/votes you need for a silver one is **4** times the number you need for a bronze one, while the number you need for a gold one is **10** times that, which comes to **1000** votes. I just don't see the relevance of 6 ...

Comment: it feels like you are on the right path.  if it helps rot13(gur evqqyr gnt vf gur bayl gnt gung unf njneqrq n tbyq (bar-gubhfnaq cbvag) onqtr.)

Comment: How are you so good at this stuff? Do you work? Are you just AI? Ahh so many questions!

Comment: @SteveV I (of all people) know that :-P The 6 is still a mystery though ...

Comment: How do you know it's not some other Tom, other SteveV and so on? Anyone can change his name any time.

Comment: @ThomasWeller That's a downside of this puzzle ... but in context, as a PSE regular, I'm pretty sure these are the users meant.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I think I solved the puzzle. Thanks for your help, I’d never have guessed without it!

Answer (score 8):

Just going to give this a try. Was not even aware that this stackExchange existed!

> 4=6 -> 4=IV, 6 = VI
> 10=1000 -> 10=X, 1000=M
>
> IV=VI
> X=M
> Step 1, remove all vertical lines
> Step 2, cut off the lower half of the character
> IV=VI --> V=V --> \/=\/
> X=M --> X=v* --> V=V
>
> *the v is floating in the air, its the "v" part of M once the vertical lines are removed

Answer (score 4):

Well...

> in many tribal languages, for example that of the [Caquintes](http://www.native-languages.org/numbers/caquinte_numbers.htm), numerals higher than two or three are just a word that means "many" (in Caquinte language's case, "oshequi").
>  So our expressions become "oshequi" = "oshequi" and "oshequi" = "oshequi". Voilà!

Answer (score 0):

> If you are asking a smart group of guys a question. aka: Tom, SteveV, Jafe, Rand, elguest, hex, Bass and others. They are all part of the same group no matter if its four people or six people